# How to View the Attribute Set of my Products

Tags: product-attribute, attribute-set, ce-1.4.1.1

Is there any clear way to view the attribute set a product is already in?  I don't see a report, and I can't find a way to see what products are already listed in each attribute set.  I'm still in Magento 1.4.1.1

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On the products grid in the backend there should be a column called `Attribute set`. You can filter by it and you can see for each product the attribute set that it uses.